# The gap was open when I was doing an HSE + SOC DFT calculation

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, band-structure, hse06

I used VASP as my DFT software to do a calculation on an anti-perovskite crystal. I try to reproduce the band structure from literature which was calculated based on HSE + SOC calculation. [Their result was shown below](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/264084992_Topological_Crystalline_Insulators_and_Dirac_Octets_in_Anti-perovskites):

[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H313bm.png)

I try to redo the calculation and plot the band along the same high symmetry line, here is what I got ( My K-point mesh is a bit low, so it may not be so smooth) :

[image: Recalculated band structure]

It seems that the two graphs are qualitatively the same. But the gap at Gamma point was open up.
I have no idea what kind of mistake I've made.
And here is my INCAR setting in my calculation:

```
 #Calculation Parameter

 ISMEAR = 0 ; SIGMA = 0.05
 PREC = Normal
 ENCUT = 350
 ISPIN = 2
 LWAVE = .TRUE.
 LCHARG = .TRUE.
 LSORBIT = .TRUE.
 MAGMOM = 15*0
 SAXIS = 0 0 1
 GGA_COMPAT = .FALSE.

#Electronic Relaxation

 EDIFF = 1E-05
 ALGO = Normal
 NELM = 500

#Ionic Relaxation

 IBRION = -1
 NSW = 0

#HSE06

 LHFCALC = .TRUE.
 HFSCREEN = 0.2
 ALGO = Damped
 TIME = 0.4
 #AEXX = 0.25
```

Comment: You should give the link to the reference paper.

Comment: I’ve already added the reference  ! Thanks for your reminder

Comment: You are not using the same parameters.

Comment: I gave you +1 long ago, but does there need to be so much space between each line in what is now the `code` block?

Comment: @Jack it would probably be enough for an answer just to point out what parameters don't match the paper.

Comment: @Jack I agree with Tyberius.

Comment: 1 The energy cutoff of the plane-wave basis is 400 eV. 2 Considering SOC the ISPIN tag is not necessary to set.

Comment: It would be good to update this. Have you tried using the same cut-off energy, ground state k-point sampling and integration method, and pseudopotentials? Are you sure you're using exactly the same geometry?

Comment: This question has been closed as it seems to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone wants to add an answer or the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.